# How to access network PC in Windows 10

Tags: windows, windows-10

I'd been able to connect to network PC using CentOS, Windows 7, Windows 8/8.1 using credentials provided by ADMIN. But using same credentials I can't connect to network PC while using Windows 10.

How can I connect to network PC using Windows 10?

Comment: What kind of network are you using?

Comment: I'm little bit unknown about the network types you are asking about. I need to access the computer in LAN connected across different buildings. I've been using Windows address-bar to enter through remote IP which allows me to get access after passing credentials. I'm doing well with Windows 8/7/8.1, CentOS but not with windows 10.

Comment: I think you're using samba. Is your adress something like `\\<severip>\<share>\<folder>`?

Comment: I'm using \\<serverip>\ in windows Explorer. This is followed by prompting for username and password. On entering the credentials in Windows 7/8/8.1, I can access network but not in Windows 10

Comment: Did you read my answer?

Answer (score 1):

Well, I think I know how to solve your problem!

Don't use the `PIN login` if you want to access your SAMBA server. 
Use `password login` instead!
I had the same problem and that solved it! :)

**That's also discussed here:** [PSA: 10240 build still has the bug of lockscreen PIN keeping SMB shares from displaying.](https://www.reddit.com/r/Windows10/comments/3dg9zt/psa_10240_build_still_has_the_bug_of_lockscreen/)

Comment: So, I find it a bit confusing. Where can I set/unset PIN login in Windows 10?